# Check array with null value, it returns me as value

Tags: php, arrays, object, null, message

I make a query to the DB if the values ​​exist and if they don't exist, I insert in DB, otherwise I need to throw an error message.
The problem is that the array of objects gets the null values ​​and interprets them to me as values, so it can't send the message.
I tried empty (array), isset (array), count (array), sizeof (array), array == undefined, and array.length. Nothing works.

This is the code when create the array:

```
if(....){
} else {
    while ($row = $consulta->fetch()) {
        if($row['total'] == 0) {
            $this->rowsFinded = [
                "id" => $id,
                "da" => $da,
                "la" => $la,
                "lo" => $lo,
                "op" => $op,
                "loi" => $loi
            ];
        }
    }
}

return $this->rowsFinded;
```

When I can't find the rows, the insertion is good. This is what I see with xdebug:

```
if (empty($rowsFinded) || !isset($rowsFinded) || is_null($rowsFinded)) {  //$rowsFinded: {[6], [6]}{2}
```

But when find the rows the result is an array with null values:

```
if (empty($rowsFinded) || !isset($rowsFinded) || is_null($rowsFinded)) {  //$rowsFinded: {[null], [null]}{2}
```

What is the problem? How can resolve this and show the message that this rows exists?

Thank you!

Comment: 1) It's redundant to call all those methods in your condition, `empty` covers both `isset` and `null`. 2) What exactly is `$rowsFinded` supposed to be? JSON string? An array?

Comment: I need $rowsFinded like an array.
I used together and alone `empty`, `isset` and `null` and the result is the same.

Comment: I meant when you wrote in your question `//$rowsFinded: {[null], [null]}{2}` - what exactly is the content of the variable, how does your code fetch it?

Comment: In $consulta-> fetch () I add in a array the mismatched values ​​in sql sentence and return this as an array with arrays. The problem is in the array because it adds me an array with null values.
`// $ rowsFinded: {[null], [null]} {2}` is the result of the PHPStorm debugger (because 2 identical rows were previously inserted).

I need to remove the null arrays.

Comment: Edit your question and show the code that does the fetching. The fix should be applied there.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the code with this and it works, so it doesn't add the null arrays to the final array:

```
      while ($row = $consulta->fetch()) {
            if($row['total'] == 0) {
                $temp = [
                    "id" => $id,
                    "da" => $da,
                    "la" => $la,
                    "lo" => $lo,
                    "op" => $op,
                    "loi" => $loi
                ];

                $rowsFinded[] = $temp;
            }
        }
```